# youtube-dl changing the format output of %(upload_date)s

Tags: bash, batch, youtube-dl

I've been downloading videos with youtube-dl using `upload_date` in the name of the file. This puts the date in YYYYMMDD format in the name file, but I will find more convenient if I could store them in something like:

- YYYY-MM-DD
- DD-MM-YYYY

I know youtube-dl does not provide that option, but is there any other way of doing this (either on Linux or Windows)? The only I can think of is mass renaming with [mmv](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-mmv/) after downloading every file.

Right now I use the output template:

```
"%(upload_date)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip how to add date at the beginning of the filename!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to change it in youtube-dl, but you can use its more advanced fork [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) and use the following output format:

```
%(upload_date>%Y-%m-%d)s
```

Working example:

```
yt-dlp -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/bestvideo+bestaudio' --merge-output-format mp4 --output "%(uploader)s - %(upload_date>%Y-%m-%d)s - %(title)s [%(id)s].%(ext)s" <URL>
```

Source: [official documentation](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#output-template).

Comment: Huge thanks for this, that's the perfect solution for the upload dates! But beware, **don't use the `bestvideo[ext=mp4]` stuff.** The yt-dlp developers have warned that this leads to lower quality downloads and lower resolution files, because YouTube prioritizes webm/VP9 for the best qualities. As an extra tip: I wanted the videos to be sorted by playlists, so this is the output format I ended up with: `-o '%(playlist)s/[%(upload_date>%Y-%m-%d)s] %(title)s [%(id)s].%(ext)s'`

Comment: @MitchMcMabers thank you for this suggestion. What would be a better way to get the best video and audio quality?

Comment: Accepted this because yt-dlp is kinda the way to go these days (youtube-dl is kinda outdated). Btw, you'd probably want to change the working example to use yt-dlp instead of youtube-dl.

In reference to what @MitchMcMabers said, I usually try first a "-F" on the URL and pick my preferred quality and format from there.

Answer (score 1):

With the [perl-flavoured `rename` command](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?q=file-rename&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8.1.0&arch=default&format=html), you could write:

```
rename 's/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1-$2-$3/' [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-*
```

I recommend you use the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD date format: it is unambiguous and it sorts the same lexically and chronologically.